# Can someone point me towards a practice C# / ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a C# / ASP.net website that I can download the source code and practice on, ideally it will come with documentation and hopefully some "bugs" or feature requests to try fixing.

Dose anyone know where to find such a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the [ASPNET starter kits](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/). They don't come with bugs for you to fix, but I'm sure you can find some lacking functionality you would like to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the open source projects on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/), there are plenty of projects you can learn from and contribute to there.

You could also go hunting for .NET projects on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to look at MVC, try the [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/). Look at the bottom of the page, you can download the source code and a sample chapter that gives a very good walkthrough of the application.